# Remove newline while writing to text

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

This simple macro will write the text "ABC" to the file temp.txt under E: drive. However if we open the text file, notice that there is a new line char after C. How can we get rid of this, so that it will end after C

Code:

```
Sub ExamplePrint
i = FreeFile()
Open "e:\Temp.txt" For Output As i
Print #i, "ABC"
Close #i
end Sub
```

In vba if we give like this, the newline doesnt come. however in openoffice the whole text document comes as empty

Code:

```
Print #i, "ABC";
```

Comment: Text files normally end with a newline, and it sounds like OpenOffice is expecting that. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Greg, Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: You showed how to avoid the ending newline with `Print #i, "ABC";`. However, you said that doesn't work with your OpenOffice. Which do you want? You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Hi,All i want is to remove the newline that comes at the end in open office. Print #i, "ABC"; works only in vba.

Answer (score 1):

Try the FileSystemObject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ee7s9w2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx